# Form Authentication on dynamic domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to implement a SSO solution that uses .Net Form Authentication.  I am aware of setting a cookie for all subdomains, like so:

```
<forms 
   name="name" 
   loginUrl="URL" 
   defaultUrl="URL"
   domain=".example.com">
</forms>
```

My questions - is there a way to make the "domain" field dynamic?  So that I could append the domain as a URL parameter?

```
http://SSO.com/?domain=example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This `domain` parameter here is used to be set on the cookies of the authentication.

You can simply ignore it, meaning do not add it at all, and the cookie will be set with whats see on the url.

Now the trick here is to make sure that your site always been with the same subdomain, eg, always make call to `www.example.com`  (not one call to www.example.com and one to example.com)

Comment: Yep, I understand that much.  I'm wondering if there's a way to keep SSO on the domain "SSO.com", and then dynamically setting which domain the cookie is assigned to.  For example, an app on "SSO.com" can set a cookie for "example.com", or whatever domain is passed in dynamically.

Comment: @user547794 For security reasons, one cookie can be set only from the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you're asking for won't work with Forms Auth out of the box.  If you set the domain to a domain other than the one you're using for authentication, your auth app won't be able to see the cookie and will think that the user is never logged in.

These sorts of things are usually handled by the domains that require the SSO making calls to the SSO domain to do authentication.  You can see this in systems like CAS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Authentication_Service) Facebook Connect or even Microsoft's Passport authentication.

If you're looking for a well-supported MS-friendly SSO, take a look at the new Azure Active Directory system (http://blogs.technet.com/b/serverandtools/archive/2012/07/12/introducing-windows-azure-active-directory-ad-web-single-sign-on-sso.aspx)